# Why can't I call a variable "chrome" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the browser console I am getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'chrome' has already been declared (at script.js:1:1)

This error only appears when the third variable is called chrome (like in the code snippet). I don't get this error, when I call the variable anything else (e.g. chromee, chrome1, etc.). Why is that? Is chrome a keyword?

This is the entire script.js:

````
let browserEngine = {
    name: "Blink",
    maintainer: "Chromium"
}

let jsEngine = {
    name: "V8",
    maintainer: "Chromium"
}

let chrome = {
    browserEngine: browserEngine,
    jsEngine: jsEngine
}

let brave = {
    browserEngine: browserEngine,
    jsEngine: jsEngine
}

console.log(chrome.browserEngine.name);
console.log(brave.jsEngine.name);```
````

Comment: can't reproduce the error - you probably have some other code that already declares that variable earlier

Comment: Seems like it depends on the browser you are using. Any browser with for example a chromium console will not allow you to do this because this variable name is already in use for something by chrome. It does however work in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Google Chrome, the browser defines a variable called `chrome`, like how you're naming it there. In JavaScript, you can't re-declare variables.

So the variable `chrome` exists, and you're trying to declare your own variable called `chrome` which causes the error.

This is specific to Chromium-based browsers, however. If you name a variable `chrome` and run the code in other browsers, you'll get no errors, but since Chromium browsers declare a variable called `chrome`, you can't declare your own variable with the name `chrome`

Comment: I don't see how this is a bug, you can't redefine location either. That's not a bug either.

Comment: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/chrome` 404 ... `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location` documented ... so ... yes, it is a bug in that `chrome` has no meaning outside of `chrome` garbage browsers

Comment: `https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/`

Comment: a web page isn't a web extension ... so ... your link is irrelevant